# How to encode HTTP response body as UTF-8 in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, utf-8

This is currently my entire node.js server code:

```
require('http').createServer(function (req, resp) {
    var html = [
        '<!DOCTYPE html>',
        '<html>',
            '<head>',
                '<meta charset="utf-8" />',
                '<title>Sample Response</title>',
            '</head>',
            '<body>',
                '<p>Hello world</p>',
            '</body>',
        '</html>'
    ].join('');

    resp.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(html, 'utf8'),
        'Content-Type': 'application/xhtml+xml;'
    });
    resp.write(html, 'utf8');
    resp.end();
}).listen(80);
```

Based on my understanding of the node.js documentation, the second 'utf8' argument to resp.write() should cause node to encode the html string as UTF-8, not the UTF-16 that JavaScript strings are natively represented as. However, when I point my browser to localhost:80, view the source, and save it to a local html file, Notepad++ tells me the file is encoded in UTF-16. Furthermore when I run it through the W3C html validator tool it also complains about "Internal encoding declaration utf-8 disagrees with the actual encoding of the document (utf-16)".

How do I force node.js to encode my HTTP response body as UTF 8?

Comment: Can you fire up a packet sniffer (Wireshark, etc.) and post a sample of what you're seeing?  I don't get this behavior.

Comment: Are you validating by file upload or pointing straight to the site?

Comment: I've tested this both with WebStorm and Sublime Text, under Linux and Windows (so that's 4 tests), and all show UTF-8. Maybe it's a Notepad++ thing ?

Answer (score 19):

maybe you have to do:

```
'Content-Type': 'application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8'
```

Comment: would it be a good idea to use the charset for sending images also, or only text?

Answer (score 14):

According to : https://www.w3.org/International/articles/http-charset/index and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields.

Recommend HTTP header looks like this:

```
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8"
```

With the two codes below, it is possible to record in utf-8 with IE8 browser.
Even if French XP32 does not allow the display of Thai characters in notepad ++.

short form :

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    var body = '<p>Hello Döm</p>\n \
  <p>How are you ?</p>\n \
  <p>ผมหมาป่า(I am The Wolf)</p>';

  res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html; charset=utf-8"});
  res.write(body, "utf-8");
  res.end(); 
});

server.listen(8080);
```

long form:

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html; charset=utf-8"});

  var title = 'Sample Response'
  var body = '<p>Hello Döm</p>\n \
  <p>How are you ?</p>\n \
  <p>ผมหมาป่า(I am The Wolf)</p>';

  var code =  [
        '<!DOCTYPE html>',
        '<html>',
            '<head>',
                '<meta charset="utf-8" />',
                '<title>' + title + '</title>',
            '</head>',
            '<body>',
                body,
            '</body>',
        '</html>'
    ].join('\n');

  res.write(code, "utf8");
  res.end(); 
});

server.listen(8080);
```

Thai characters are well preserved if I record from IE8 in an HTML page.

Comment: should one also send the utf-9 header for images?

Answer (score 1):

Believe it or not, this problem I'm having with the internet is due to... Internet Explorer. In this case, Internet Explorer 11 thinks it's acceptable to save the results of the View Source window in UTF-16 no matter what the original page encoding. So, my test page from localhost was saved as utf16, google.com was saved as utf16, etc. etc. Installed Firefox and its utf8 as far as the eye can see.

I didn't believe them when they said IE is a terrible browser. I guess we all have to learn sometimes.

:(

Answer (score 0):

If you are using "**node-http**", then you do it as follows:

```
result.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain; charset=utf-8"});
```

If you are using "**express**", then you do it as follows:

```
result.set({ 'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8' });
```

Assuming a scenario where you are returning your data from a database, you have to also ensure that your charset is set to "utf-8".

Go to your database connection and add utf8mb4 as your charset
as follows:

```
mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'db_host',
    port: 3306,
    user: 'root',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'database',charset : 'utf8mb4',
    
});
```

If you are supposed to return characters that include unicodes then your best bet would be to set your charset to "utf8mb4" as it supports more characters...goodluck.